# python delete function not working in apache

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-s3

I am using the s3cmd linux utility to delete files from our amazon s3 bucket. I have created a function in python which calls the s3cmd command line utility and access and deletes the files amazon s3 bucket.

```
command= 's3cmd -c .s3cfg del s3://project-bucket/images/testimage.jpg'
os.system(command)
```

When I run the project through django development server, it works fine. The image is deleted.

But if I run on apache it does not work. The image is not deleted. I checked the apache error logs, they are no errors in the apache log. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the apache user has permission to write for all the images and folders you are deleting from.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 10.04 and checked in my /etc/apache2/envvars, its mentioned as:

export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

checked the permission on amazon bucket, the file has full permissions for owner and read permission for everyone.

Comment: once again, right now, i tried by giving full permissions to everyone, but still it does not get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is resolved. gave 777 permissions to the .s3cfg file and now i am able to list the image as well as delete the image.